# Сортировка списка кортежей по двум параметрам

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, list, tuple

Мне нужно отсортировать кортеж:

```
[('AB', 80), ('BAA', 80), ('AA', 100), ('AB', 100), ('A', 50)]
```

Нужно отсортировать кортеж сразу по двум параметрам, сортировка 0 элемента по алфавиту и сортировка 1 элемента по убыванию числа.

То есть на выходе должен получиться кортеж:

```
[('AA', 100), ('AB', 100), ('AB', 80), ('BAA', 80), ('A', 50)]
```

Сортировка такого типа, не даёт нужный мне результат:

```
s = [('AB', 80), ('BAA', 80), ('AA', 100), ('AB', 100), ('A', 50)]
s.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)
```

Выход:

```
[('AB', 100), ('AA', 100), ('BAA', 80), ('AB', 80), ('A', 50)]
```

Comment: у вас немного странное представление о сортировке по алфавиту - почему вы ожидаете, что `'A'` в отсортированном списке будет стоять в самом конце?

Comment: @MaxU возможно, имеется ввиду сортировка по убыванию числа, а среди совпадающих - по алфавиту строки

Comment: @MaxU нужна сортировка и по алфавиту и по убыванию числа. В вопросе я это написал.

Comment: @Jack_oS, похоже на то. Хотя судя по формулировке - `сортировка 0 элемента по алфавиту и сортировка 1 элемента по убыванию числа` должно быть наоборот. Мы все-таки читаем слева-направо ;)

Comment: @Максим смените тональность: никто здесь, думаю, не подписывал с вами контракт на выполенение заданий, тем более поданых с двусмысленной формулировкой

Comment: @Максим, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение для сформулированного вопроса:

```
data = [('AB', 80), ('BAA', 80), ('AA', 100), ('AB', 100), ('A', 50)]
res = sorted(data, key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]))
```

результат:

```
In [158]: res
Out[158]: [('A', 50), ('AA', 100), ('AB', 100), ('AB', 80), ('BAA', 80)]
```

---

Решение для ожидаемого результата (в данном случае сначала сортируем кортежи по второму элементу по убыванию, а уже потом для совпадающих вторых элементов, сортируем по алфавиту первые элементы):

```
res2 = sorted(data, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))

In [164]: res2
Out[164]: [('AA', 100), ('AB', 100), ('AB', 80), ('BAA', 80), ('A', 50)]
```

**NOTE:** попробуйте внятно сформулировать вопрос - порядок имеет значение!

Comment: Я же в вопросе чётко указал, что мне нужна сортировка по двум значениям. 
Первый элемент должен быть ('AА', 100).

Comment: @Максим По двум значениям можно сортировать в разном порядке. Вам уже несколько раз это сказали, а вы не хотите понимать. Судя по предоставленному примеру сортировка по числу должна идти сначала, а потом уже сортировка по алфавиту. Так и надо писать в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо за ваше разъяснение )
Никака не мог найти [информацию](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) по моей задаче, а тут ваша демонстарция с отрицаетельным ключом!

У меня была задача отсортировать список `data = [(34, 3), (36, 4), (35, 5), (32, 4), (37, 2), (33, 1), (30, 1), (68, 1), (31, 1), (48, 1), (45, 1)]`. Где второй параметр должне идти по убыванию, а первый по возрастанию.

```
res = sorted(data, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
```

res = [(35, 5), (32, 4), (36, 4), (34, 3), (37, 2), (30, 1), (31, 1), (33, 1), (45, 1), (48, 1), (68, 1)]

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте ответа, нажав [edit], что нового добавляет ваш ответ.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо».  Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [проголосовать за вопросы и ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), которые сочтёте полезными. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/707193)